# array from continuous data?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a quite difficult problem that i cant wrap my head around.. hope you can help me!

Lets say my data is in A1:G1 for example:

```
A1   B1   C1   D1   E1   F1 G1

X    X    0    X    X    X   0  
or
Y    X    X    X    X    Z   X
```

The thing i would need to come up with is how to get array from this data according to the X, BUT if like in example 1 there is 2 times X in the beginning and 3 x next to each other so the array should come out like {2;2;0;3;3;3;0} so i want the array to be 7 long and the array should show the x as number how many are next to each other.

example 2 should come out like {0;4;4;4;4;0;1}

if you can figure this out would really help me alot!

Edit:

Trying to give out better, more bigger picture of what i mean..

if data is :

```
    A   B   C  
1   X   X
2       X   X
3   X
```

it should come  out as

```
    A   B   C
1:  2   4   0 
2:  0   4   2
3:  1   0   0
```

or in array {2\4\0;0\4\2;1\0\0}

on B1 and B2 there should be 4 because the formula should count horizontal but also vertical continuum. I tried to use usmanhaqs formula but i was not able to modify it so the count resets on every line.
Real size of the table is 7 times 7 cells.

I will use the array with another array (scoreboard which is also 7 times 7 cells, and has numbers 1, 2 or 3 on every cell) using sumproduct and it will give out the points of that player.

I appreciate your efforts on helping out a newbie learner on vba :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly did you try, and what was the result? Please go through the guide on [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that others may be able to provide you with better assistance.

Comment: So you are only looking for X, not for any other letters? Do you have room for helper columns/rows, or is it important that the solution is a single formula?

Comment: i have figured how to do it with multiple formulas and with multiple sheets, but i wanted to simplify this for the user and i just couldnt wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this code

```
Function get_array(r As Range, match_chr As String)

    Dim check_val
    Dim array_value

    array_value = "{"

    For i = 1 To r.Count

    check_value = r.Item(i)

        If (check_value = match_chr) Then
            j = i + 1
            Do While (j <= r.Count) And (check_value = r.Item(j))

                j = j + 1
            Loop

            array_value = array_value & WorksheetFunction.Rept(j - i & ", ", j - i)
            i = j - 1
        Else
            array_value = array_value & "0, "
        End If

    Next

    array_value = Left(array_value, Len(array_value) - 2) & "}"
    get_array = array_value


End Function
```

You can use it as below

[image]

**EDIT**

find below another function to return an array of values that can be used in the formulae

```
Function get_number_array(r As Range, match_chr As String)

    Dim check_val
    Dim array_value
    Dim number_array(1 To 50) As Long

    For i = 1 To r.Count

    check_value = r.Item(i)

        If (check_value = match_chr) Then
            j = i + 1
            Do While (j <= r.Count) And (check_value = r.Item(j))

                j = j + 1
            Loop

            For k = 1 To j - i
                number_array(i + k - 1) = j - i
            Next k

            i = j - 1
        Else
            number_array(i) = 0
        End If

    Next

    get_number_array = number_array


End Function
```

You have to use it same as the previous one, but it will return excel array.

Comment: This was really nice vba-code, but.. i cant use this as array, since there are the spaces between every character. i tried to remove them from the code and for some reason the last digit leaves out from the solution. eny ideas?

edit: i figured this out, but another problem came up, this soluion is in quotemarks "" and i cant use it in functions that need arrays. for excample sumprodcuts..

Comment: What is your exact goal, I can try to update the code to achieve that. Currently this function is returning the array as a string as per your original question, you can not use it in sum, average type functions.

Comment: I have added another function to return number array that can be used in the excel formulae

Comment: The excact goal is to calculate the result of a board game called kivi,

Comment: goal of the function means what you would do with the returned array, but anyhow i have edited the answer and you may have already seen, you can use the returned array in the excel formulae.

Comment: My apologies, new to the forum. Goal is to use this function/array with sumproduct. I quess i should have posted the whole problem and not just part of it  just wanted to try and figure it out by myself (learning is fun) i will try to edit the original post with the full question.. Thanks for your patience

Comment: sumproduct is used on at least two arrays? which one is the second?

Comment: Second array is table with numbers from 1 to 3, see if my edited original question answers your question

Comment: i think it will require some sort of recursive functions logic because in a 7x7 matrix their can be a lot of combinations of continuity, i shall try to do that and will let you know.

Comment: ok i have checked it and it is a lot of codding and from the solution point of view it is totally different from your first question. As you have already received two answers for your first question, i fear you will not receive any more for your new edit. It is better to keep this thread for the first one you have asked and make a new one for the new edit so that some relevant person can answer it. A second option is to unmark this answer as selected answer and hopefully someone will answer your question. but do upvote it as helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For a formula solution, I can only come up with one for the special case where you have just X's and zeroes (example 1) so far:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:G1<>"X",0,INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:G1="X",COLUMN(A1:G1)),IF(A1:G1<>"X",COLUMN(A1:G1))),N(IF({1},SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,0,0,1,COLUMN(A1:G1)))))+1,1)))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I have wrapped it in a SUM function to demonstrate that it generates an array which can be passed to another function (result: 13) or it can be array-entered across several cells:

[image]

Comment: I am becoming fan of yours, your answers really fascinate me, each time I see your answer I always get something new to learn. Still I don’t know how to use frequency and if({1} was new to me. I have googled frequency few times but I believe I have to search more.

Comment: Thank you! Although I didn't manage a general answer to this question, it is quite a good case study of various techniques (which I have learnt from masters like @Barry Houdini) - I will add some references later.